# How to NOT redeploy whole application in Tomcat after each small change?

Tags: java, tomcat, jar, war

I have a big application which is packaged as a WAR file and it contains bunch of JAR files in it.

The load time of this application is huge. And I have to redeploy the whole app when I do a minuscule change to the application (which literally affects one class/one JAR).

So, I am wonder whether there is a way to speed up this whole thing?

This will be done in a development environment. So, some tricks which have side effects are fine.

I saw this question:
[Tomcat: hot deploying new jars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390487/tomcat-hot-deploying-new-jars)
However, it's old (5 years old).

Also, it would be really strange if it's not possible. I believe there are a lot of java enterprise apps which are big and It's hard to imagine all developers waiting for the whole app to redeploy after tweaking couple of lines of code.

Comment: take a look at [jrebel/](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/)

Comment: try to read these answers, and yes JRebel should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998669/redeploy-alternatives-to-jrebel