# how to replace library in shared/lib tomcat without restart the server?

Tags: java, web-services, maven, tomcat, spring-boot

I am trying to do a project with micro-webservices with spring boot and tomcat. My idea is pull apart each one services in different projects.

However there are shared services. For this I thought of creating the shared services like web services, however the final system increases the latency, for this reason I think doing it like library `.jar` and share the folder in tomcat with `shared/lib` and change the `conf/catalina.properties`  file [like here](http://www.programania.net/diseno-de-software/ficheros-war-sin-las-librerias-del-proyecto-con-maven-y-tomcat/) with:

```
shared.loader=${catalina.home}/shared/lib,${catalina.home}/shared/lib/*.jar
```

The problem occurs when I replace the library .jar for a newer version, I have to restart the server tomcat and all web services within, this is not ok.

Could someone tell me other option to do it?

Regards.

Comment: Libraries are loaded on deploy time, dependencies are resolved and so on. That's how it is. Also, why not giving each one its jar file on WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: Seems similar to [Tomcat hot deploying new jars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390487/tomcat-hot-deploying-new-jars)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I did not put the libraries within the WEB-INF/lib because I want to remplace it in anytime without the need  to recompile the web service. The .jar could be a utility library.

Comment: The Jack G's link solution does not work in my case, each time that I changed the library the server rebooted, please some one knows other solution?.

I do not know if this is what I want to do is correct, 
Have someone tried separate the services SOAP like in my case?